# Ruby on Rails: Variables in Functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, model

I wondering if I can somehow make "stat" a variable in the following function:

```
  def stats(stat)
    self.items.sum(:stat) + self.stat
  end
```

I'm wondering how to make :stat in self.items.sum(:stat) a variable. I'm not sure about the syntax.

Sorry if this is a horribly newbish question.

Items migration:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :title

      t.text :content

      t.integer :price

      t.integer :strength
      t.integer :agility
      t.integer :intellect
      t.integer :will
      t.integer :perception

      t.integer :hearm
      t.integer :laarm
      t.integer :raarm
      t.integer :charm
      t.integer :llarm
      t.integer :rlarm

      t.integer :damage

      t.integer :hardpoints

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Characters migration:

```
class CreateCharacters < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :characters do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.text :bio

      t.integer :strength
      t.integer :agility
      t.integer :intellect
      t.integer :will
      t.integer :perception

      t.integer :hearm
      t.integer :laarm
      t.integer :raarm
      t.integer :charm
      t.integer :llarm
      t.integer :rlarm

      t.integer :currency

      t.integer :user_id      

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That wont work for sure. But everything is possible with ruby :) How do you want to call that function? With a symbol representing a field of the model? Or that isn't a model?

Comment: Basically, I have a number of items that belong to a character. There are six stats attached to each item and the character itself. The goal of the function is to add the stats of all possessed items together and add them to the corresponding stat of the character.

I can do it in a less-DRY way within the controller, and I am, but I would like to make it a function to which I can send a stat name.

Comment: Please show us your data structures

Comment: but stat is already a variable (formal parameter, but still) in that method - maybe you need to post a bit more source code to help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I updated the original question with my item and character models.

Comment: Also, I'm super-fuzzy on what various things are called in rails at the moment since i haven't worked in it in a while.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a variable in the sum(:stat) portion of self.items.sum(:stat) + self.stat. Basically making :stat a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure what you want to

```
def stats(stat)
  stat = stat.to_sym
  items.sum(stat) + read_attribute(stat)
end
```

`stat = stat.to_sym` is just to ensure it's a symbol, so you can pass a string and it will still work, but it's not need if you only pass symbols.

so you you should call it as

`character.stats(:strength)` or `character.stats('strength')`

Comment: That sounds like what I want. I'll read up on to_sym. Thanks man!

Comment: if it helped don't forget to accept it. Take in mind that it might be good idea to move that in a single query for better performance, if you always call that method for each stat, and do some caching maybe.